# upload all fields with the image file upload optional PHP MySQLI

Tags: php, mysqli

I have searched far and wide and cannot find an answer to my question in terms that I can understand. I am trying to make my code upload all text input fields and if not image is in the file input, then upload all except the image and upload all including the image when an image is present. Below is my working code for when an image is present. All help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

$userID = $_SESSION['usr_id'];

if(!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"])) {
$eTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['etitle']);
$eDate=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['edate']);
$eDesc=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['edesc']);
$file_tmp = $_FILES['uploadedimage']['tmp_name'];
$file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['uploadedimage']['name'])));
$date = date("d-m-Y");
$imagename = $date."-".time().".".$file_ext;
$target_path = "event_images/".$imagename;  
$move = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $target_path);
if($move) {
    if($_FILES['uploadedimage']===false){
        $not = "NULL";
    }ELSE{
        $not = $imagename;
    }

    $sql =mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `events` (eventID,eventImage,eventTitle,eventDate,eventDescription) values (NULL,'".$not."','".$eTitle."','".$eDate."','".$eDesc."')");
    $db = mysqli_query($sql, $con);
    $msg = "Song has been uploaded successfully";
    header("Location: websiteeditor.events.php");
}
else {
    $msg = "Not uploaded because of error #".$_FILES["file"]["error"];
}

} 
else {
    $msg = "Failed to Upload<br/>Not uploaded because of error #".$_FILES["file"]["error"];
}

?>
<?=$msg;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code should work the way you need it.

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$userID = $_SESSION['usr_id'];

$eTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['etitle']);
$eDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['edate']);
$eDesc = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['edesc']);
$date = date("d-m-Y"); // where is this used?

$not = null;
if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"])) {
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['uploadedimage']['tmp_name'];
    $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['uploadedimage']['name'])));
    $imagename = $date . "-" . time() . "." . $file_ext;
    $target_path = "event_images/" . $imagename;
    $move = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $target_path);
    if ($move) {
        $not = $imagename;
    } else {
        $msg = "Not uploaded because of error #" . $_FILES["file"]["error"];
    }
}

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `events` (eventID,eventImage,eventTitle,eventDate,eventDescription) values (NULL,'" . $not . "','" . $eTitle . "','" . $eDate . "','" . $eDesc . "')");
$db = mysqli_query($sql, $con);
$msg = "Song has been uploaded successfully";
header("Location: websiteeditor.events.php");

?>
```

Comment: the $date was also used in the $imagename variable for adding the date to the imagename itself

Comment: @vampnerdlord best way to thank me is to give the answer an upvote :)